# How to insert an List of string array into a table rows in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Hi I have a MVC project and I am calling a POST to get data from server-side which works great!

I have a bootstrap css table to which I want to bind all the data in the call back function for POST.

Below is my code snippet:

**JS & VM**

```
var map;
var updateFeature;
function OpCropData(opCropName, opET, opEffRain, opCIR, opRecharge) {
var self = this;
self.opCropName = ko.observable();
self.opET = ko.observable();
self.opEffRain = ko.observable();
self.opCIR = ko.observable();
self.opRecharge = ko.observable();
}

var VM = function (){
require([
  "esri/map",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/dijit/AttributeInspector",


  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
  "dojo/_base/Color",

  "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
  "esri/config",

  "esri/tasks/query",

  "dojo/parser",
  "dojo/dom-construct",
  "dijit/form/Button",

  "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!"
],

function (
  Map, FeatureLayer, AttributeInspector,
  SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, Color,
  ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, esriConfig,
  Query,
  parser, domConstruct, Button
) {
    parser.parse();

    var self = this;
    //ComputedCropData Values
    self.ComputedCropData = ko.observableArray([OpCropData()]);

    // refer to "Using the Proxy Page" for more information:  https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
    esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy";

    map = new Map("mapDiv", {
        //basemap: "county",
        //center: [-97.395, 37.537],
        //zoom: 5
    });

    map.on("layers-add-result", initSelectToolbar);

    var petroFieldsMSL = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://server18/ArcGIS/rest/services/TestMaps/CIR/MapServer");
    petroFieldsMSL.setDisableClientCaching(true);
    map.addLayer(petroFieldsMSL);

    var petroFieldsFL = new FeatureLayer("http://server18/ArcGIS/rest/services/TestMaps/CIR/MapServer/7", {
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
        outFields: ["OBJECTID", "SCTCOR_ID", "DIR", "TWNSHP", "RNG", "SECTION_", "X_COORD", "Y_COORD"]
    });
    var selectionSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
      SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL,
      new SimpleLineSymbol(
        "solid",
        new Color("blue"),
        2
      ),
      null
    );
    petroFieldsFL.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol);

    petroFieldsFL.on("edits-complete", function () {
        petroFieldsMSL.refresh();
    });

    map.addLayers([petroFieldsFL]);



    function initSelectToolbar(evt) {
        var petroFieldsFL = evt.layers[0].layer;
        var selectQuery = new Query();

        map.on("click", function (evt) {
            selectQuery.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
            petroFieldsFL.selectFeatures(selectQuery, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {
                if (features.length > 0) {
                    //store the current feature
                    updateFeature = features[0];
                    map.infoWindow.setTitle(features[0].getLayer().name);
                    map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
                } else {
                    map.infoWindow.hide();
                }
            });
        });

        map.infoWindow.on("hide", function () {
            petroFieldsFL.clearSelection();
        });



        var layerInfos = [{
            'featureLayer': petroFieldsFL,
            'showAttachments': false,
            'isEditable': false,
            'fieldInfos': [
              { 'fieldName': 'OBJECTID', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'OBJECTID:' },
              { 'fieldName': 'SCTCOR_ID', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'SCTCOR_ID:' },
              { 'fieldName': 'DIR', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'DIR:' },
              { 'fieldName': 'TWNSHP', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'TWNSHP:' },
              { 'fieldName': 'RNG', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'RNG:' },
              { 'fieldName': 'SECTION_', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'SECTION_:' },
              { 'fieldName': 'X_COORD', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'X_COORD:' },
              { 'fieldName': 'Y_COORD', 'isEditable': false, 'label': 'Y_COORD:' }

            ]
        }];

        var attInspector = new AttributeInspector({
            layerInfos: layerInfos
        }, domConstruct.create("div"));

        //add a save button next to the delete button
        var saveButton = new Button({ label: "Save", "class": "saveButton" });
        domConstruct.place(saveButton.domNode, attInspector.deleteBtn.domNode);//, "after");

        //add a data button 
        var dataButton = new Button({ label: "Data", "class": "dataButton" });
        domConstruct.place(dataButton.domNode, attInspector.deleteBtn.domNode, "after");


        dataButton.on("click", function GetTRS() {
            var objectID = updateFeature.attributes.OBJECTID;
            var Direction = updateFeature.attributes.DIR;
            var Township = updateFeature.attributes.TWNSHP;
            var Range = updateFeature.attributes.RNG;
            var Section = updateFeature.attributes.SECTION_;
            $.post("/Home/Index", { "T": Township, "R": Range, "S": Section }, function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    self.ComputedCropData.push(data[i]);
                }
            }, 'json');

        });
        map.infoWindow.setContent(attInspector.domNode);
        map.infoWindow.resize(350, 240);
    }
})};

 $(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applyBindings(new VM());
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<table class="Computed CIR table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center"><b>Crop</b></th>
            <th style="text-align: center"><b>ET (inches)</b></th>
            <th style="text-align: center"><b>Eff.Rain (inches)</b></th>
            <th style="text-align: center"><b>CIR (inches)</b></th>
            <th style="text-align: center"><b>Recharge (inches)</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ComputedCropData">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="text: opCropName"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="text: opET"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="text: opEffRain"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="text: opCIR"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="text: opRecharge"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The data returned from post is a LIST of string arrays with each array having the five data types I am trying to bind to the cells in each row of the table.

Thank you in advance!!

***I updated my working model with no binding issues the only issue I have currently is that the ko.observable array "self.ComputedCropData" does get pushed with all the data but the view is not updated***

Comment: I assume you forgot to add the knockoutjs tag?

Comment: it's better to write your viewmodel to get the right answer

Comment: I am kind of new to Knockout as well so i am not sure if I can use the  View model function as I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

The data that comes back in your callback needs to be attached to your viewmodel somehow.  I'm not sure how you're creating your viewmodel, but if you have something like this:

```
var vm = {
    data: ko.observableArray([])
}
```

then you'd need to update that data array in your ajax callback.

```
$.post("/Home/Index", 
       { "T": Township, "R": Range, "S": Section }, 
       function (data) { vm.data(data); }, 'json');
```

That assumes that your data observable array is holding plain old JavaScript objects, which is fine.  If however you need these objects to be mapped over to objects with knockout observables, then you'd have to map it somehow. You could either map everything over manually, or use [knockout's mapper](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)